# Handling redirects when using mixins for ModelAdmin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have some ModelAdmin classes, their `ModelForm`s are based one the same one ModelForm class.

```
class RepairAdmin(RedirectMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
   pass

class PurchaseAdmin(RedirectMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
   pass
```

I need to define specific behavior for some of the `redirect_` methods, so I've written `RedirectMixin`:

```
class RedirectMixin(object):
    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
        if request.POST.get('_continue'):
            return super(self.__class__, self).response_add(request, obj)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:requests_request_changelist'))
```

The problem is that I can't use `self.__class__` with `super()` - I get "maximum recursion exceeded" exception. But I can't specify the class itself, I don't know if it is PurchaseAdmin or RepairAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But that's the point, you don't need to know. A super call must always use the class that you define it in. Python resolves the reference using the MRO.

```
class RedirectMixin(object)
    def response_add(...):
        ...
        return super(RedirectMixin, self).response_add(...)
```